# Gradle project dependency error in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jenkins, gradle

I have a project structure similar to

```
//Directory structure
Root Folder/
   projectA/
      build.gradle
   projectB/
      build.gradle
      properties.gradle
```

Now, project B is dependent on project A

The settings.gradle and build.gradle for Project B is as follows

**settings.gradle**

```
include   ':ProjectA'
project(':ProjectA').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../ProjectA')
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies{
   compile project(':ProjectA')
}
```

When I try to build project B on my local machine (Gradle version 3.2) it builds successfully and everything looks good.

When i try to build the same project in jenkins (same gradle version as my local), i am getting the error

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.UnknownConfigurationException: Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

It looks like in jenkins, it is not able figure out the relative path.

How do I solve this?

Is there a way in jenkins I can ignore the dependency from gradle and use the pre build to compile ProjectA and put that in the classpath? If so how can we do it?

Comment: In your `settings.gradle`, why complicate things by renaming the project? Please post your full `build.gradle` files.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Thanks for looking into this. I updated the question adding the dependency section for build.gradle. I was able to solve this look at the answer

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding a jenkins property which I check in the build file

```
if (project.hasProperty('jenkins')) {
  dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
  }
} else {
   dependencies {
    compile project(':ProjectA')
  }
}
```

So when we build it locally, since we are not passing the property it is able to compile ProjectA. In Jenkins, the build job, in the gradle command I am passing the following ***-Pjenkins clean build***. This goes to the if condition and pulls the jar from projectA and puts that in the lib directory.

This has solved the problem for me, let me know if there are better solutions for it